# How to give default value and placeholder to redux form select field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have array iterating options of redux form option... How I will give dafault value and place holder because it shows the first value of array which don't want... I want to show the placeholder instead

```
  <Field
    name="facilityId"
    component="select"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="sdsfdsafjdsafijdsaoi"
  >
    {owners.map((data, i) => {
      return (
        <option value={data._id} key={i}>{data.profile.name}</option>
      )
    })}
  </Field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following

```
<ControlLabel>Patients</ControlLabel>
    <Field
        name="facilityId"
        component="select"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="sdsfdsafjdsafijdsaoi"
    >
        <option value="-1" disabled>Choose patient</option>
        {owners.map((data, i) => {
            return (
                <option value={data._id} key={i}>{data.profile.name}</option>
            );
        })}
    </Field>
<FormControl.Feedback />
```

PS: Sorry if the formatting is off. I'm typing with my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Using Redux-form, multiple select fields, and loading the options asynchronously - I had issues w/ the chosen answer not working 100% of the time. This works in my case. Notice the `value` is `""`.

```
<ControlLabel>Patients</ControlLabel>
<Field
    name="facilityId"
    component="select"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="sdsfdsafjdsafijdsaoi"
>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose patient</option>
    {owners.map((data, i) => {
        return (
            <option value={data._id} key={i}>{data.profile.name}</option>
        );
    })}
</Field>
```

Comment: Thanks I will check and let you know